# I am running Lucid, Ubuntu one is installed but I don't have a menu item to run it

Tags: 10.04, menu

I don't know how to run it from the terminal. I tryed unity --reset, a command I found in a response to a similar question, but got the error message `No command 'unity' found`.
Thanks for any suggestions you can make.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt` to launch the Control Panel for Ubuntu One.

As for `unity --reset` not working, Unity was not a part of Ubuntu in Lucid Lynx. It became a part of Ubuntu from Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat.